# custom headers for static home page and posts page

Tags: customization, pages, headers

have a site w/a static home page and a posts page and then a number of other static pages - i set up a custom header for the home page and then another all other pages like this in the header

```
<?php
if(is_home()){
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header_front.php');}

else {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header_default.php');}

?>
```

it works perfectly except that the posts page is displaying header_front.php instead of header_default.php

so i guess im asking how i get wordpress to realize that the posts page isnt the home page

Comment: use  is_front_page() for static front pages.

Comment: You're using the wrong conditional. "is_home()" applies to the Blog Posts index, whether displayed on the Front Page or not. As Wyck said, you need to use "is_front_page()" if you want to output something (or not) on the Front Page.

Comment: yeh i tried that already and it displayed header_default.php on both the static home page and the blog - so it did change the header on the blog but it unfortunately changed it on the home page too - v frustrating  - thx tho!

Answer (score 5):

### Instead of using include(TEMPLATEPATH use the built in WordPress API.

The WordPress API accommodates for using different headers.

```
<?php 
       if (is_front_page() ) {
               get_header( 'front' );

        } else {
               get_header();
       }
?>
```

Your custom header template should be named header-front.php and your default header should be named header.php

Answer (score 0):

ok so i guess there was some code in  the template for the home page that i c&ped off some site that was making wordpress think it was the blog page - once i excised that and then did is_front_page() everything was cool - so thx

this is the code if anyone might be at all interested - i was under the impression it was necessary to designate a template - obvs theres a bunch of extra stuff in there tho

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: blog
*/
$pagenum = $wp_query->query_vars;
$pagenum = $pagenum['paged'];

if (empty($pagenum)) {
$pagenum = 1;
}

query_posts("posts_per_page=10&paged=$pagenum");
?>
```